# Why does my solution to this nodal analysis problem not work?

Tags: dc, nodal-analysis

Observe the following schematic, in which I am trying to calculate the value of \$V_1\$:
[image]
Let \$i_1\$ be the current in the left hand loop. Then \$i_1 = v_1 \div 50 \$ and also \$i_1 = (600 - v_1) \div 10\$. Setting these two equations equal yields \$v_1 = 500\$.

What did I do wrong? The given answer is 583.3 V for \$ v_1 \$.

Comment: You should express the voltage \$v_2\$ as it matters for determining \$i_1\$. Voltage \$v_2\$ depends on the 15-A source and the current derived by the 30-ohm resistor.

Comment: I get their answer really easy. Just convert 15 A and 30 Ohm (Norton) to its 450 V and 30 Ohm Thevenin. This means 1050 V total supply across a 40 Ohm + 50 Ohm divider pair. Or 1050 * 50 / (50 + 40) which gives their value quickly. So this sanity check says they are right. Another way is to just look at the current in the voltage loop, lose the current source for a moment, and find (600/90) as the current. Then add 1/3rd of 15 A (because that is how it divides over the two branches) and add it. That times 50 ohms gives it: ((600/90)+5)*50. Same answer.

Comment: @VerbalKint but why isn't the voltage drop across the 10-ohm resistor just 600 - v1? And I should be able to determine i1 from that. That is what I don't understand. *why* does v2 matter for determining i1.

Comment: The voltage of the 100 ohm resistor is 600 + v2 - v1

Comment: @Krauss I assume you mean the 10-ohm resistor. Why is that? My book says if we have a voltage source between a nonreference node and reference node we just take the nonreference node to be the value of the voltage source. Does this not apply if there are other elements like resistors in series with the source? Why/why not?

Comment: The problem is asking for nodal analysis and you are making loop analysis. Sum the currents entering to node v2.

Comment: `also i1=(600−v1)÷10` nope. Check where the reference/ground is, and where the voltage source is referenced to.

Comment: @xormapmap The 600V power source is not connected to reference

Comment: @RohatKılıç and Krauss (multiple tags don't work sorry) but these two comments did more to further my understanding of this in the space of 5 seconds than I have gotten after hours of my own frustration. Thank you. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you assumed that right side of 600 V voltage source (v2) is at 0 V, which is false. Correct equation is i2 = (v2 + 600 V - v1) / 10 ohm.